# Differential Privacy guarantee that takes into account the approximate density (e.g., the pseudo randomness) used in practice?

Tags: similarities, approximation, differential-privacy

In theory the differential privacy guarantee comes from adding randomness to an algorithm so whatever is output is a sample from a target distribution (e.g., the Laplacian, Gaussian, Exponential Mechanism's distribution, etc.) In practice, one must use a pseudo random generator or other approximation method to generate the randomness. In short, the samples used in practice not from the "real" density (say $p(x)$), they are from an approximate density (say $q(x)$).

Are there theorems to quantify how using the approximate density $q$ affects the privacy guarantee?

On example of how this may work: suppose we can compute the dissimilarity of the approximate density to the "real" one, e.g.,  by sampling from the approximate density many times $x_i\sim q, i = 1, ..., n$ we can compute an empirical KL divergence $(1/n) \sum_{i = 1, .., n} \log(q(x_i)/p(x_i))$ so long as we can compute $p(x)$. Is there work relating the quantified difference in the densities to the privacy?